# Create array from multi-dimensional one with jq

Tags: json, hierarchical-data, jq, data-extraction

I would like to use 'jq' json processor to transform a json structure to an array of simple objects.

My structure is like this:

```
{"nsgs": [
    {
        "comments": "text1",
        "properties": {
            "securityRules": [
                {
                    "name": "1",
                    "properties": {
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "2",
                    "properties": {
                        "protocol": "UDP",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "comments": "text2",
        "properties": {
            "securityRules": [
                {
                    "name": "3",
                    "properties": {
                        "protocol": "TCP",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "4",
                    "properties": {
                        "protocol": "UDP",
                        "sourcePortRange": "*"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]}
```

And what I want to get is:

```
[
{ "comments": "text1",
  "name": "1",
  "protocol": "TCP",
  "sourcePortRange": "*"
},

{ "comments": "text1",
  "name": "2",
  "protocol": "UDP",
  "sourcePortRange": "*"
},

{ "comments": "text2",
  "name": "3",
  "protocol": "TCP",
  "sourcePortRange": "*"
},

{ "comments": "text2",
  "name": "4",
  "protocol": "UDP",
  "sourcePortRange": "*"
}
]
```

I tried lots of approaches but nothing helps.

Will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following filter, laid out here for easy reading, will aggregate the input as requested:

```
.nsgs
| map(.comments as $comments
      | .properties.securityRules[]
      | {comments: $comments,
         name, 
         protocol: .properties.protocol,
         sourcePortRange: .properties.sourcePortRange } )
```

If you wanted to avoid the repetition in the last two lines, you could replace the last four lines with:

```
      | {comments: $comments, name }
        + (.properties | {protocol, sourcePortRange} ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution:

```
.nsgs | map({comments} + (.properties.securityRules[] | {name}+.properties))
```